# How to iterate over large number of records in MySQL with memory efficient manner in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I want to fetch all records from a table using `findAll` and do some processing on each of them, but I'm not sure if it will give memory issues if the number of records is huge like in millions.

I have looked into the `Pageable` but I'm not sure how to iterate over all the data using `Pageable` approach. Is it even possible to fetch few records at a time process them and fetch them again until all the records are processed?

And what would be better? Fetch all the records in Iterable using `findAll()` method or the Pageable approach?

Comment: You intend to update the records or just READ the data?

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong tool. Once you need to scale up, and the problem space becomes a big data problem - you should consider using big data tools, i.e spark, kafka, ...

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I intend to only read the data and do some processing over it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't use findAll if there is a lot of entities.

If you want to use pagination you can do something like this:

```
    Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 200);
    Page<Qmail> onePage = repository.findAll(pageRequest);

    while (!onePage.isEmpty()) {
        pageRequest = pageRequest.next();

        //DO SOMETHING WITH ENTITIES
        onePage.forEach(entity -> System.out.println(entity.getId()));

        onePage = repository.findAll(pageRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Don't you think *onePage = repository.findAll(pageRequest);* this will again fetch the same results? Since pageRequest still has the page number 0 and size 200?

Comment: No since there is a `pageRequest.next()` that will move to next page

Comment: `pageRequest.next()` will return Pageable instead of PageRequest. So this approach will fail nowadays. However you could change last line to `onePage = repository.findAll(pageRequest.nextPageable());`. It should work.

Comment: Use while (!onePage.isLast()) instead of while (!onePage.isEmpty()), It would going to save last extra loop

Comment: It is a bit confusing that your first statement in that while loop is pageRequest.next();
I would move it to the last statement where it is actually needed 

onePage = repository.findAll(pageRequest.next());

Answer (score 5):

Since Spring Data 1.8 you can `Stream` over results.

```
Stream<Record> findAll();
```

Important is here that you add a `QueryHint` about the fetch size for the database. If set it internally uses pages for streaming over the results.

Use this for MySQL databases:

```
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "-2147483648"))
Stream<Record> findAll();
```

For none-MySQL databases you can play with the fetch size:

```
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "5000"))
Stream<Record> findAll();
```

And, if you do not update / delete the records, do not forget to set your transaction to read-only:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

If it can be millions..

**1)** Do not use `findAll()` and retrieve a list of actual managed entities. If you only need to read the data then use a projection query along with Spring Data JPA projection interface. This will bypass the persistence context and save a lot of time and memory.

**2)** Use Paging (to save memory) and make sure make each call in a new transaction (`@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)`). This will allow other transactions not to hang forever which might be the case if you did NOT use paging and triggered only one, give me all, query.

**3)** It looks like a candidate for an overnight batch job also. Think about that.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is read data as a batch and process each of them and may be persist same somewhere else or generate report out of it.

This the ETL use case.

Spring Batch can be used for this case which can handle it very well.

Reader reads the data one at a time and process it in processor. Writer will persist or generate report based on chunk/batch size you set.

This way you are not holding a lot of data in memory.